# How do I test a private method of a class in Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, typescript-eslint

I am using react typescript.

So I have a similar setup of classes like this in my project. Foo has two member methods `a and b`. **b is a private method**. There's a class Buzz which is responsible for data fetching and calls the private method passed to it when it is complete.

```js
class Buzz {
  callLater({ onMsg }) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      onMsg('Buzz completed')
    }, 2000)
  }
}

class Foo {
  a() {
    console.log('calling a');
    const buzz = new Buzz()
    buzz.callLater({onMsg: this.b})
  }

  private b(msg) {
    console.log('calling b');
    console.log(msg)
  }

}
```

I want to test the private `method b` in typescript and I am doing something like this below. But when the test runner runs `(jest)` it fails and says `fooInstance.b` is not a function

```
const foo = new Foo();
const fooInstance = (Foo.prototype as unknown) as { b: () => void };

fooInstance.b()
```

Not understanding how I will be able to test it. Stuck for hours.

Comment: `How do I test a private method of a class in Jest` [You don't](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/380287/why-is-unit-testing-private-methods-considered-as-bad-practice). To elaborate - private methods are implementation details, they should be able to be changed without consequence. Only ever focus on testing the public things that call the private ones. When should you create private methods is another question entirely

Comment: I know it isn't a good practice. But I am not clearly able to understand how would I test this

Comment: Assert on the _behaviour_ - does the message get logged?

Comment: Actually you can assume the Buzz class works more like an Observable. So it would call b when data is streamed over that observable.

Comment: `I know it isn't a good practice. But I am not clearly able to understand how would I test this`. b is a private method (so typescript makes it inaccessible to you unless you do some dirty hacks) - what calls `b`? Whatever the thing is that calls b, test that thing instead. If nothing calls `b` except your planned unit test, then you should delete it

Answer (score 0):

> There's a class Buzz which is responsible for data fetching and calls the private method passed to it when it is complete.

So what's the responsibility of `Buzz`? The responsibility of it is to call the argument passed into it. You don't care what the argument is, just that the buzz instance needs to call it when appropriate.

What's the responsibility of `foo.a`? It's to create a buzz that calls it's `callLater` method that `console.log`'s the message from buzz. You don't care that it's done by calling `foo.b`, the same outcome could be achieved by writing the code this way:

```
class Foo {
  a() {
    console.log('calling a');
    const buzz = new Buzz()
    buzz.callLater({onMsg: console.log})
  }

}
```

**Don't test your implementation details, test your behaviour.** (like jonsharpe said)